# "Install Ubuntu" leads to black screen and doesn't load

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to dual-boot Ubuntu 18.04.1 alongside Windows 10 on a Yoga 720 laptop. I've created a bootable USB with Rufus, and using Advanced Startup Options I am able to boot from the USB. However, once it loads the initial screen and I select "Install Ubuntu," the screen goes black and stays that way until I reboot into Windows 10. Please help!

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu, I had a similar issue and I had to disable ACPI before booting the installer. See [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/set-acpi-off-kernel-parameters-for-ubuntu-linux-installation) for reference.

Comment: Try booting with nomodeset option enabled.